# Dragging mouse in emacs results in strange output

Tags: key-bindings

If I click and drag my mouse within a buffer, garbage text appears all around the mouse.

I have tried (global-set-key [drag-mouse-1] 'mouse-set-region) with no effect.  I have otherwise no explicit remapping of mouse-1.  How can I redefine normal drag-mouse-1 behaviour or at least disable the current action?

Comment: You're using emacs in a terminal? It sounds like you may be interested in `xterm-mouse-mode`.

Comment: The `drag-mouse-1` event is generated at the end of the drag, not *during* the drag.